# PHP code to download CSV file not working

Tags: php, csv

I have the below code, where I generate random numbers and try to download them as a CSV file.

If I try the CSV code snippet alone on a different file it works, but in this code, it just does not work. I do see the random numbers echoed, but it does not download the CSV file.

```
<?php

$dataarray=array();

function convert_to_csv($input_array, $output_file_name, $delimiter)
{
$temp_memory = fopen('php://memory', 'w');
foreach ($input_array as $line) 
{
fputcsv($temp_memory, $line, $delimiter);
}

fseek($temp_memory, 0);
header('Content-Type: application/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachement; filename="' . $output_file_name . '";');
fpassthru($temp_memory);
}

for ($i = 0; $i <= 25000; $i++) 
{ 
  $num = (rand(50,110));

  array_push($dataarray,"$num");

  echo "Hearbeat #" .$i . "\t\t ------   " . $num;
  echo "<br>";
}

convert_to_csv($dataarray, 'data_as_csv.csv', ',');

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outputting data **before** sending headers with `header()` means that `header()` calls will have **no** effect. So it is reasonable not to send anything before headers.

As another answer mentioned - second argument to `fputcsv` must be array, so I changed the call to `fputcsv` too.

If you want all values to written to csv file with comma as separator - pass `$input_array` directly to `fputcsv`.

So, your code can look like:

```
<?php
$dataarray=array();

function convert_to_csv($input_array, $output_file_name, $delimiter)
{
$temp_memory = fopen('php://memory', 'w');

// Option 1 - every number will be on a new line
foreach ($input_array as $line) 
{
// add `array($line)` not `$line`
fputcsv($temp_memory, array($line), $delimiter);
}

// Option 2 - all numbers will be in 
// one line with `$delimiter` as separator
fputcsv($temp_memory, $input_array, $delimiter);

fseek($temp_memory, 0);
header('Content-Type: application/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachement; filename="' . $output_file_name . '";');
fpassthru($temp_memory);
}

for ($i = 0; $i <= 25000; $i++) 
{ 
  $num = (rand(50,110));
  array_push($dataarray,"$num");

  // this two lines are nor needed
  //echo "Hearbeat #" .$i . "\t\t ------   " . $num;
  //echo "<br>";
}

convert_to_csv($dataarray, 'data_as_csv.csv', ',');
```

Comment: thanks a lot. 1- I want the values appear on the screen, so I kind of need the echoes, but putting it, stops the download of the file. + the values are not seperated by commas in the generated file.

Comment: You __must__ understand that there is only __one__ option - either download file or view webpage. There's __NO__ way to do both in php.

Comment: If you need values separated by commas, then as @gmc said - pass `$input_array` to `fputcsv`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the problem is in your `convert_to_csv` function. 
`fputcsv` expects the second parameter to be an array, and in you case is a string. You have 2 options depending on what you want:

1) Each number in a separate line: just change the `fputcsv` function call to: `fputcsv($temp_memory, [$line], $delimiter);`

2) All numbers in the same line separated by `$delimiter`:

```
function convert_to_csv($input_array, $output_file_name, $delimiter)
        {
            $temp_memory = fopen('php://memory', 'w');

            fputcsv($temp_memory, $fields, $delimiter);
            fseek($temp_memory, 0);
            header('Content-Type: application/csv');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachement; filename="' . $output_file_name . '";');
            fpassthru($temp_memory);
        }
```

And (I'm sure you already know), for the file to be downloaded automatically you must not `echo` anything.

Comment: Seriously - you put all values from one array `$input_array` to another array `$fields`? Why?